# Multiple radio input checked

Tags: javascript, checkbox, input, radio-button, mustache

My problem seems quite simple but i can't see what's going wrong.
I am just trying to have a simple multiple-choice form with only one choice possible, with the help of radio inputs.

I am using a loop with Mustache.js and I believe it prevents it from working, because I can select every input at the same time

Here's the code

```
<ul class="list-group mongroupe">{{#liens}}<form>
<li class="list-group-item"><div  onclick="sessionStorage['idpatient']='{{patient}}'">
<input type="radio" name="listemp" value={{patient}}/><h2> {{patient}} </h2> </div>
</li></form>
{{/liens}}
</ul>
```

Even though the inputs have the same name (others questions take this for a solution).
I'd thankful for a hint on how to solve this.

Comment: A form is not a valid child of an UL, so the markup is invalid.

Comment: @adeneo That is not true.

Comment: Please show rendered HTML

Comment: @CyberDude - What's not true? Can you have a form as a direct child of an UL ?

Comment: Yes, see http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form for instance: "Contexts in which this element can be used: Where flow content is expected."

Comment: @CyberDude - You still can't have a form as a direct child of an UL

Comment: Why is that? Show me some references

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `form` outside the `ul` or at least outside the `#liens` block. Your rendered HTML probably has one form for each radio button which means each radio is alone in it's own group.